# How to pass array as a parameter for rowMode="array" in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

I would like to get the result of a query using rowMode="array" (as this is a potentially very large table and I don't want it formatted to object format) but I couldn't figure out how to pass in a array/list parameter for use in an IN operator.

```js
const events = await t.manyOrNone({text: `select * from svc.events where user_id in ($1:list);`, rowMode: "array"}, [[1,2]]);
```

However, the above gives an error: syntax error at or near ":"

Removing the :list did not work either:

```js
const events = await t.manyOrNone({text: `select * from svc.events where user_id in ($1);`, rowMode: "array"}, [[1,2]]);
```

Error: invalid input syntax for integer: "{"1","2"}"

I understand that this might be because I'm forced to use ParameterizedQuery format for rowMode="array" which does not allow those snazzy modifiers like :list, but this then leads to the question, if I were to use ParameterizedQuery format, then how do I natively pass in a Javascript array so that it is acceptable to the driver?

I guess an alternative formulation to this question is: how do I use arrays as parameters for ParameterizedQuery or PreparedStatements...

Comment: `how do I use arrays as parameters for ParameterizedQuery or PreparedStatements...` - this would be the right question, because use of those indeed forces server-side query formatting, so you cannot use things like formatting filters. But you do not need to use `rowMode`, there are better ways to handle large tables, that's what you should look for.

Comment: Hi @vitaly-t, can you point me out to where I should look when handling large data SELECTs, instead of rowMode? I had assume rowMode is more optimized as there is no need for data translation. What I am trying to avoid is to pass a large table in object-key format between database -> nodeJS -> front-end.

Comment: It is called data pagination. And object-key format isn't large, unless you make it. You are looking at traffic optimization the wrong way.

Comment: Ok, I think data-pagination is a really another topic, I am already looking into that, but i would still like to optimize the efficiency of a data-heavy site (regardless of pagination concerns).

Can I veer back to the original question... is there any method to pass a Javascript array in as a parameter for ParameterizedQuery / PreparedStatement? I just like to know if it is possible. e.g. how I can run `select * from users where user_id in ($1)`, where $1 is a Javascript array. I can't figure this out! Or am I stuck with using the server-side query formatting? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Hi, after experimentation I found that the array is actually accepted, but we need to use the ANY()  instead of the IN operator, which actually accepts array as input (doh! silly of me to overlook this!). As such I will close and answer this question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I eventually found an answer to this issue: how to pass in arrays as params for use in the IN operator when using `rowMode="array" | ParameterizedQuery | PreparedStatements`.

Because this query is being parameterized in the server, we cannot use the IN operator, because the IN operator parameterize items using `IN ($1, $2, $3...)`. Instead we need to use the ANY operator, where `ANY($1)` where for $1 an array is expected.

So the query that will work is:

```
const events = await t.manyOrNone({text: `select * from svc.events where user_id=ANY($1);`, rowMode: "array"}, [[1,2]]);
```